# How come Google search never gets slower? Doesn't it have to go through the ever increasing amount of data on the internet and then rank?

Tags: search

I heard Google creates indexes of pages. Even then, the number of indexes goes with time. Why wouldn't this slow down the search?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The google indexing and search is run in parallel using a [map-reduce algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce).
As the number of pages to index expands, so does the number of computers that google uses for the task.

Currently Google handles about [3.5 billion searches per day](http://www.internetlivestats.com/google-search-statistics/).
A single search uses [1 000 computers](http://www.internetlivestats.com/google-search-statistics/) in parallel (each computer holds $\frac{1}{1000}$ of the total Google index) and takes on average 0.2 seconds.

Servers available for search are always in read-only mode. When the search index gets updated those servers are temporary unavailable for search.

Given the current amount of floor-space in its data centres Google has a maximum of about [1.7 million servers](https://plus.google.com/+JamesPearn/posts/VaQu9sNxJuY).
Obviously most of these are devoted to something other than search.